# Getting an address of point on click within polygon in yandex map

Tags: javascript, yandex-api, yandex-maps

I'm using yandex map to identify whether address is inside of particular company's delivery zone.

I've found already working sample ([yandex delivery zone api](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/delivery_zones?from=club)) with drawing polygons in map. It works well, but I need to get an delivery address inside of polygon.

Issue is that, when we click the polygon's area, we cannot get address of clicked point.

How to get an address inside of polygon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Yandex.Maps API you can set [interactivity model](https://tech.yandex.com/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Polygon-docpage/#param-options.interactivityModel) for an object. It describes which events would be generated by the geoObject and which of them would be 'visible' on the map level.